# Illegal pattern character 'Y' on Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows-7, ubuntu-10.04, simpledateformat, playframework-1.x

I use this pattern `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");` in windows and it works, but when try on Ubuntu 10.04 it show an exception `play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: Illegal pattern character 'Y'`.

I search for solution for this and found the year pattern must be change to lower-case:
`SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");` and it works.

**Can anyone can tell me the reason behind this why in Windows works but in Ubuntu didn't work if I use 'Y' instead of 'y'?**

Note:

1. Play-1.2.3
2. JRE:

   1. Windows: `java version "1.7.0_03"
      Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
      Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)`
   2. Ubuntu: `java version "1.6.0_31"
      Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04)
      Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)`
3. Windows 7
4. Ubuntu 10.04

**Update 24/05/2012**

After I check again in my system, there is 3 JRE and my windows using JRE1.7 for default. But for Play I set running using JRE1.6.

Comment: Because the Ubuntu implementation follows the API documentation? Without digging into the source, this may just be an opinion answer, but someone else may know more.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I search for SimpleDateFormat and got the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) from oracle.

Works in my windows because I set the default JRE to 1.7 but still running using JRE1.6 for the Play Framework.

[image]

Works on Windows because of this, JRE1.7 has added 'Y' pattern for `Week year` and in JRE1.6 there is no pattern for this.

Answer (score 14):

`Y` is not an valid pattern. `y` is.

As per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Letter   Date or Time Component     Presentation    Examples
G        Era designator             Text            AD
y        Year                       Year            1996; 96
M        Month in year              Month           July; Jul; 07
w        Week in year               Number          27
...
```

I don't know why `Y` would work in windows, but it is not documented. `y` is the correct one. And the safest.

Comment: Is it maybe because the different JRE that I use? For Windows I'm using JRE from Oracle but not sure if my Ubuntu using same JRE, because another person installing for me.

Comment: @Crazenezz - run `java -version`